# Vuetify v-list-group

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js

How to close other list-groups when opening a list-group?

Apparently class `v-list-group--open` gets added to .v-list-group and some more stuf down the source when opening it..

```
<v-list>
  <v-list-group>
    <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
      <v-list-item title="Bliep" v-bind="props" max-height="10">
      ...

  </v-list-group>


  <v-list-group>
    <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
      <v-list-item title="Blop" v-bind="props" max-height="10">
      ...

  </v-list-group>

  <v-divider />
</v-list>
```

Comment: The `v-list` have the attribute `open-strategy`, if you set to `single` it will open just one element of the group.